# Solr returning wrong type of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr

I'm using solr for search.

In my model I have -

```
searchable do
  integer :rank
  text :title, :descritpion
  text :aboutuser do
    users.map { |user| user.aboutuser }
  end

  text :username do
    users.map { |user| user.username }
  end
end
```

And then in the controller -

```
def index
@books = Book.search do
  fulltext params[:search]
  order_by :rank, :desc
end
...
```

In the server log the query looks to have the right things in it -

```
SOLR Request (7.0ms)  [ path=select parameters={fq: ["type:Book"], sort: "rank_i desc", q: "Every", fl: "* score", qf: "title_text descritpion_text aboutuser_text username_text", defType: "edismax", start: 0, rows: 30} ]
```

But rather than returning Book objects, it's returning this:

```
#<Sunspot::Search::StandardSearch:0x007fe6bf4f3550>
```

Which is causing an undefined method error when the view renders. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `results` to get your actual objects.